# Installing a new dll to GAC using post build event is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, build-process, gac

I've written a post build script for my visual studio project

```
copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)\..\..\BuildDependencies\$(TargetFileName)"
if exist "$(ProjectDir)..\..\gac_dll" "$(FrameworkSdkDir)\bin\gacutil.exe" /i "$(TargetPath)" /f
```

The following is the build output.

```
Build started: Project: ****** Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

****** -> C:\VSVN Repos\**\**\**\**\**\bin\Debug\**.dll

copy "C:\VSVN Repos\**\**\**\**\**\bin\Debug\**.dll" "C:\VSVN Repos\**\**\**\**\**   \\..\..\BuildDependencies\**.dll"

if exist "C:\VSVN Repos\**\**\**\**\**\..\..\gac_dll" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\bin\gacutil.exe" /i "C:\VSVN Repos\**\**\**\**\**\bin\Debug\**.dll" /f

1 file(s) copied.

========== Build: 4 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The output shows that the file has been copied. But when i checked GAC, the old dll is still there.It was not removed from GAC. Does anyone has any idea why the file has not been copied?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at your syntax in your post build event: "\v6.0A\bin\gacutil.exe"" there is a double "\" before bin.